# Failed .NET Framework 3.5 installation

Tags: sql-server-2008, installation

I am trying to install SQL Server 2008 Enterprise, but it give an me an error saying Microsoft .NET framework 3.5 installation has failed.

I tried to install .NET framework 3.5 separately, then install SQL Server again but it gave same error. How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 2):

> .Net Framework should be built into Windows 8 and 10 already and you
>   can enable it from control panel.

Do the following to enable .Net Framework on your Windows

1. Press `Windows + R` keys on the keyboard.
2. Type “*appwiz.cpl*” in the “Run” command box and press “ENTER”.
3. In the “Programs and Features” window, click on the link “Turn Windows features on or off”.
4. Check if the “*.NET Framework 3.5 (includes .NET 2.0 and 3.0)*” option is available in it.
5. If yes, then enable it and then click on “OK”.

Follow the on-screen instructions to complete the installation and restart the computer, if prompted

Answer (score 1):

In Windows Server 2008 R2, Do the following steps.

1. Open Uninstall Program from Control Panel.
2. Click on "Turn Windows On or Off" from left Pane.
3. In Action Menu, Click Add Features.
4. Check .Net Framework 3.5.1 Features (Installed) and Click Next.
5. Complete the Installation and then Continue Installing Ms SQL
   Server.

Answer (score 0):

Have you try to remove and reinstall .Net Framework ?
You can try to install .NET 4.0 too...
Otherwise, could you send us your error message ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. Press Windows Key + R
2. Type 'optionalfeatures' Then Enter.
3. Check On Microsoft .Net Framework 3.5.1 Option.
4. Press OK.